# Is this necessary to use a message bus and DDD architecture for Microservices

Tags: .net, microservices

I had read a lot of documents about Microservices in .NET
and most of them use (message bus, DDD architecture, Event Handler, Commands, ...)
and these are confusing, are these necessary?
Is this ok for Microservices that I just break my application into many little APIs with their own database with clean architecture or onion architecture without (message bus, DDD architecture, Event Handler, Commands, ...)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more suitable for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: should I ask in stack exchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether your architecture choices are "okay" for your purpose is a matter of opinion and up to you.

The reason you see event-driven, message plane architecture so often with Microservices is that it's a reliable, scalable, well-managed way to allow communication between microservices **without having them directly interact with each other**.

This is a very common antipattern with new microservices architects where one "microservice" is directly contacting - via HTTP or gRPC or some other protocol - other microservices.  Having this be the case necessarily couples services together making what is more properly considered a [distributed monolith](https://www.gremlin.com/blog/is-your-microservice-a-distributed-monolith/).

Embracing the concept of [smart endpoints and dumb pipes](https://simplicable.com/new/smart-endpoints-and-dumb-pipes) (in your example - the messaging plane being a series of dumb pipes) is the proper way to achieve real separation of services and the resiliency that microservices is intended to provide.